# MySQL: How to get leaderboard position, for each event in a series

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data structure (simplified):

```
Users:
    ID
    Name

Events:
    ID
    Date

Results:
    ID
    User ID (foreign key)
    Event ID (foreign key)
    Points: (int)
```

I would like to know (ideally the most efficient way):

- How to get a user's position in a 'league' compared to other users. And - - If possible using one query (or sub queries), how to break this down by event, e.g. the user's position after the 1st event, 2nd event, 3rd event etc.

I can get the leaderboard with:

```
select users.name, SUM(results.points) as points
from results
inner join users on results.user_id = users.id
group by users.id
order by points DESC
```

However, I'd like to know a user's position without having to return the entire table if possible.

Edit: I have supplied some sample data [here](https://gist.github.com/SteveEdson/606518d120dcd550ce9eb66f3678e1dd).

Ideal output:

```
| User ID | Rank  |
| 3       | 1     |
| 1       | 2     |
| 2       | 3     |
```

and something similar to (not exactly like this, it's flexible, just something that shows the user's rank from each event)

```
| User ID | After Event | Rank  |
| 1       | 1           | 1     |
| 1       | 2           | 1     |
| 1       | 3           | 2     |
| 2       | 1           | 2     |
| 2       | 2           | 2     |
| 2       | 3           | 1     |
| 3       | 1           | 3     |
| 3       | 2           | 3     |
| 3       | 3           | 3     |
```

Comment: Are you trying to create something where a user inputs a user's name and the event name and you want to return the user's position after that event? Also, it would really help if you can add some sample data.

Comment: Sample data and output would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I've added the sample data to a gist link. I have control over the server, so I can use any version of MySQL, however at the moment, it's 5.7. I'm trying to create something that when the user is logged in, it shows their current league position, and ideally, a graph of each user's position, after each event, to see the change in positions over time

Comment: when user gets logged in pass userid and and add where condition then get league position

Comment: @SteveEdson if you kindly share expected result data set from your input data that would be helpful to answer

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin done

Comment: @SteveEdson i have edited my answer have you checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0+ supports [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) so the use of `dense_rank()` comes in handy.

---

**MySQL under 8.0 solution**

Since your version is 5.7 you could imitate this like below:

```
select 
  t.id,
  CASE WHEN @prevRank = points THEN @currRank
       WHEN @prevRank := points THEN @currRank := @currRank + 1
   END AS rank
from (
  select users.id, SUM(results.points) as points
  from results
  inner join users on results.user_id = users.id
  group by users.id
  order by points DESC
  ) t
  cross join (SELECT @currRank := 0, @prevRank := NULL) r
```

If you need data for particular `user` then add a `WHERE` condition to filter out everyone else in an outer query:

```
select *
from (
<< above query here >>
) t
where id = ? -- your id here
```

---

**MySQL 8.0+ solution**

`rank` is a reserved keyword so backticks are required when naming a column. We're using `dense_rank` window function which will assign ranks based od descending sorting of points acquired:

```
select id, dense_rank() over (order by points desc) as `rank`
from (
  select users.id, SUM(results.points) as points
  from results
  inner join users on results.user_id = users.id
  group by users.id
  ) t
order by `rank`
```

Comment: This works well for all users, but adding a `where` changes the rank to 1, because there's no others to increment it

Comment: Updated answer to clarify what I mean. You need one more level of select statement.

Comment: That's perfect thank you. Don't suppose there is a way to show the rankings after each event is there (taking into account the points from the last event)?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but more complicated (especially for MySQL version under 8.0 as you want cumulative sum of points).

Comment: No problem, is it possible to provide an example for MySQL 8 please?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @rowno = 0;
select UserID, max(points), @rowno:=@rowno+1 as rank  from 
(
select users.id as UserID ,users.name as users_name,events.name, SUM(results.points) as points
from results
inner join users on results.user_id = users.id
inner join events on results.event_id= events.id
group by users.id,events.name,users.name
order by points DESC
) as T
group by UserID

order by max(points) desc
```

Comment: Sorry, I know how to do this, I've updated my question with an example of the desired output.

Comment: @SteveEdson i have edited my answer can you please check now